# Problems with the onclick in React

Tags: html, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create a function that serves as a card counter so that when I press the + button a card is added and - when subtracted to prevent more than 4 equal cards. My problem is that I'm afraid that React's onclick and onClick is colliding with JS and Html. I am new to React and would like to solve this question please.

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  const [equipo, setEquipo] = React.useState([]);
  let listaCartas = Array();
  let listaPrecios = Array();
  let campoCartas = document.getElementById('muestroCartas');
  let idArticulo = 0;
  let contador = 1;


  // Constructor
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Magic - React";
    obtenerDatos();
  }, []);

  // Metodo que recoge info de una Api
  const obtenerDatos = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Augin&unique=prints");
    const info = await data.json();
    setEquipo(info);
  };

  // Metodo que funciona como un carrito de compra
  // que muestra las cartas elegidas
  const carrito = (nombreCarta, precioCarta) => {
    listaCartas.push(nombreCarta);
    listaPrecios.push(precioCarta);
    campoCartas.innerHTML += "<b>Nombre: </b>" + nombreCarta + " <b>Precio: </b>" + precioCarta + " € <b>Cantidad</b><p id='numero" + idArticulo + "'>" + contador + "</p><br><button onclick='masCartas(idArticulo)'>+</button><button onclick='menosCartas(idArticulo)'>-</button><br>";
    idArticulo++;
  };

/**
* METODO QUE REALIZA LA SUMA
* DEL NUMERO DE CARTAS ELEGIDAS
* @param {*} idArticulo contador de la carta metida en carrito
*/
//function masCartas(idArticulo) {
const masCartas = (idArticulo) => {
  let numeroStock = parseInt(document.querySelector("#numero" + idArticulo).innerText);
  numeroStock++;
  if (numeroStock > 4) {
    alert("No puede tener mas de 4 cartas iguales");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#numero" + idArticulo).innerText = numeroStock;
  }
}
/**
* METODO QUE REALIZA LA RESTA 
* DEL NUMERO DE CARTAS ELEGIDAS
* @param {*} idArticulo contador de cuantas cartas tiene en carrito
*/
//function menosCartas(idArticulo) {
const menosCartas = (idArticulo) => {
  let numeroStock = parseInt(document.querySelector("#numero" + idArticulo).innerText);
  numeroStock--;
  if (numeroStock < 0) {
    numeroStock = 0;
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#numero" + idArticulo).innerText = numeroStock;
  }
}

return (
  <div className="App">
    <div class='leftDiv'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Imagen</th>
          <th>Venta</th>
        </tr>
        {equipo?.data?.map((item) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td><img src={item.image_uris.normal}></img></td>
            <td><button onClick={() => carrito(item.name, item.prices.eur)}>Añadir</button></td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class='rightDiv'>
      <h2>Cartas escogidas</h2>
      <div id='muestroCartas'></div>
    </div>
  </div >
);
}

export default App;
```

The moment I hit the add or subtract button when a card is added I get an error on the console that says "Uncaught ReferenceError: masCartas is not defined onclick Two.css:1" and I don't understand how it shows error in the css if it supposedly has nothing to do with one component with another.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is not how things are usually done in React - you don't want to modify the `innerHTML` property by dynamically assigning raw code to it.

I suppose the problem you have at the moment is that the `masCartas` function is defined inside of the component, but doesn't exist in the `innerHTML` you render. The argument you pass (`idArticulo`) will not contain the value you expect as well.

In order to fix it, change the code modifying `<div id='muestroCartas'></div>` via `innerHTML` to this div having [children](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) (all the HTML code you wrote will have to be rewritten to React components).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,it would be a comment, but i am not allowed. I am still looking for the id 'numero', where is it? I see that you trying to manipulate it(innerText), but i can't find it.

An advice, we don't use query selector on React, because we work with states, so i recommend you study more about states in React.

Comment: It's hard to understand a working model like React just like that. Thank you very much for responding and I'll look at that from the states.